# Hash Tables: Ransom Note - Hacker Rank in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I'm preparing for an interview doing the [preparation questions](https://www.hackerrank.com/interview/interview-preparation-kit) on Hacker Rank and I want to become better at this. Is it possible to get some feedback on this? How can I improve my code? How did you solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps) question?

```js
function getCount(array){
    let counts = {}
    for(let word of array){
        let count = counts[word]
        counts[word] = count ? counts[word] + 1: 1;
    }
    return counts
}
// Complete the checkMagazine function below.

function compareNoteMag(note,mag){
    let noteKeys = Object.keys(note)
    let string = 'Yes'
    for(let key of noteKeys){
        if(!mag[key]) string = 'No'
        if(mag[key] < note[key]){
            string = 'No'
        }
    }
     console.log(string)
}

function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {
    let magazineCount = getCount(magazine);
    let noteCount = getCount(note);
    compareNoteMag(noteCount,magazineCount)
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might have some better luck asking this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Max I got some good answers there :D

Answer (score 3):

**Giving couple of solutions example with time complexity this might help**

**Solution 1 :**  this is okay for couple of test cases but u will fail some of the test cases as per below
Constraints as the number of magazine and note length increase it will fail to execute within time limit set by hackerank https://www.hackerrank.com/environment

[image]

```
function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {

    
    for (var i = 0; i <= note.length; i++) { //O(n)
        for (var j = 0; j <= magazine.length; j++) { //O(n)
            if (note[i] == magazine[j]) {
                
                magazine.splice(magazine.indexOf(magazine[j]), 1) //O(n)
                note.splice(note.indexOf(note[i]), 1) //O(n)


            }
        }

    }
    let result = (note.length > 0) ? "No" : "Yes"
    console.log(result)
}
```

**Solution 2 :** better as compare to solution 1 but this will also fail some of test cases

```
    function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {
    let result = "Yes"
    note.forEach((n) => { //O(n)
        if (magazine.includes(n)) { //O(n)
            magazine.splice(magazine.indexOf(n), 1) //O(n) 
        }
        else {
            result = "No"
            return
        }

    })
    console.log(result)
}
```

**Solution 3 :** better from above two this should pass all the test cases as here we are using js object which kind of HashTable so accessing element cost u O(1)

```
function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {
     let hash_mag = {}
     let result = "Yes"

     magazine.forEach((m)=>{ //O(n)
         hash_mag[m] = hash_mag[m] ? hash_mag[m]+1 : 1
     })

    note.forEach((n) => { //O(n)
        if (hash_mag[n]>0) { //O(1)
            hash_mag[n] =  hash_mag[n] - 1 //O(1)
        }
        else {
            result = "No"
            return
        }

    })
    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution to your third solution, but my solution fails some test cases while yours didn't. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the specific test cases that fail. Can you help me understand the difference between my solution and yours? My solution is here: https://github.com/boxcarcoder/test/blob/main/Hash%20Table/ransomNote.js

Comment: the only difference there is pre and post-increment in magazine loop, if you change your code from table[magazine[i]]++ to ++table[magazine[i]] or table[magazine[i]]+1 then your solution should work